# Convert for loop to list comprehension to form a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a dictionary as the input based on which the second dictionary is formed in the following code:

```
dict1 = {'a': 'ok', 'b': 'ok', 'c': 'needs repair'}

final_dict = {}
for d in dict1.items():
    if d[1] == 'ok':
        final_dict[d[0]] = 'needs repair'
    else:
        final_dict[d[0]] = 'ok'

print(final_dict)
```

where it prints out:

```
{'a': 'needs repair', 'b': 'needs repair', 'c': 'ok'}
```

How to change the for loop to a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension - list comprehensions make not much sense here:

```
# what to change into what
flipper = {"ok":"needs repair", "needs repair":"ok"}

source = {'a': 'ok', 'b': 'ok', 'c': 'needs repair'}
flipped = { key:flipper[value] for key, value in source.items()}

print(source)
print(flipped)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'ok', 'b': 'ok', 'c': 'needs repair'}
{'a': 'needs repair', 'b': 'needs repair', 'c': 'ok'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could re-write your for loop into a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), like this:

```
dict1 = {'a': 'ok', 'b': 'ok', 'c': 'needs repair'}

result = {k: 'needs repair' if v == 'ok' else 'ok' for k, v in dict1.items()}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 'needs repair', 'b': 'needs repair', 'c': 'ok'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single dict comprehension as follows:

```
>>> final_dict = {k: 'needs repair' if v == 'ok' else 'ok' for k, v in dict1.items()}
>>> final_dict
{'a': 'needs repair', 'b': 'needs repair', 'c': 'ok'}
>>>
```

In practice, I'd split the long line:

```
final_dict = {k: 'needs repair' if v == 'ok' else 'ok'
              for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better choice if you would've asked for dictionary comprehension

```
final_dict = { k: 'needs repair' if v=='ok' else 'ok' for k,v in dict1.items()}
```